# Make D3.js charts responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I am have created chart using d3.js, when I zoom in or zoom out on web browser this charts do not re-size according to window.
Following is what I have done:

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <style type="text/css">

                    svg {
                      font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica;
                    }

                    .line {
                      fill: none;
                      stroke: #000;
                      stroke-width: 2px;
                    }

            </style>
            <body>
                <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
            <script>

                        var m = [20, 20, 30, 20],
                            w = 960 - m[1] - m[3],
                            h = 500 - m[0] - m[2];

                        var x,
                            y,
                            duration = 1500,
                            delay = 500;

                        var color = d3.scale.category10();

                        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                            .attr("width", w + m[1] + m[3])
                            .attr("height", h + m[0] + m[2])
                          .append("g")
                            .attr("transform", "translate(" + m[3] + "," + m[0] + ")");

                        var stocks,
                            symbols;

                        // A line generator, for the dark stroke.
                        var line = d3.svg.line()
                            .interpolate("basis")
                            .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
                            .y(function(d) { return y(d.price); });

                        // A line generator, for the dark stroke.
                        var axis = d3.svg.line()
                            .interpolate("basis")
                            .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
                            .y(h);

                        // A area generator, for the dark stroke.
                        var area = d3.svg.area()
                            .interpolate("basis")
                            .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
                            .y1(function(d) { return y(d.price); });

                        d3.csv("stocks.csv", function(data) {
                          var parse = d3.time.format("%b %Y").parse;

                          // Nest stock values by symbol.
                          symbols = d3.nest()
                              .key(function(d) { return d.symbol; })
                              .entries(stocks = data);

                          // Parse dates and numbers. We assume values are sorted by date.
                          // Also compute the maximum price per symbol, needed for the y-domain.
                          symbols.forEach(function(s) {
                            s.values.forEach(function(d) { d.date = parse(d.date); d.price = +d.price; });
                            s.maxPrice = d3.max(s.values, function(d) { return d.price; });
                            s.sumPrice = d3.sum(s.values, function(d) { return d.price; });
                          });

                          // Sort by maximum price, descending.
                          symbols.sort(function(a, b) { return b.maxPrice - a.maxPrice; });

                          var g = svg.selectAll("g")
                              .data(symbols)
                            .enter().append("g")
                              .attr("class", "symbol");

                          setTimeout(lines, duration);
                        });

                        function lines() {
                          x = d3.time.scale().range([0, w - 60]);
                          y = d3.scale.linear().range([h / 4 - 20, 0]);

                          // Compute the minimum and maximum date across symbols.
                          x.domain([
                            d3.min(symbols, function(d) { return d.values[0].date; }),
                            d3.max(symbols, function(d) { return d.values[d.values.length - 1].date; })
                          ]);

                          var g = svg.selectAll(".symbol")
                              .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + (i * h / 4 + 10) + ")"; });

                          g.each(function(d) {
                            var e = d3.select(this);

                            e.append("path")
                                .attr("class", "line");

                            e.append("circle")
                                .attr("r", 5)
                                .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.key); })
                                .style("stroke", "#000")
                                .style("stroke-width", "2px");

                            e.append("text")
                                .attr("x", 12)
                                .attr("dy", ".31em")
                                .text(d.key);
                          });

                          function draw(k) {
                            g.each(function(d) {
                              var e = d3.select(this);
                              y.domain([0, d.maxPrice]);

                              e.select("path")
                                  .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values.slice(0, k + 1)); });

                              e.selectAll("circle, text")
                                  .data(function(d) { return [d.values[k], d.values[k]]; })
                                  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.date) + "," + y(d.price) + ")"; });
                            });
                          }

                          var k = 1, n = symbols[0].values.length;
                          d3.timer(function() {
                            draw(k);
                            if ((k += 2) >= n - 1) {
                              draw(n - 1);
                              setTimeout(horizons, 500);
                              return true;
                            }
                          });
                        }

                        function horizons() {
                          svg.insert("defs", ".symbol")
                            .append("clipPath")
                              .attr("id", "clip")
                            .append("rect")
                              .attr("width", w)
                              .attr("height", h / 4 - 20);

                          var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
                              .range(["#c6dbef", "#9ecae1", "#6baed6"]);

                          var g = svg.selectAll(".symbol")
                              .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");

                          area
                              .y0(h / 4 - 20);

                          g.select("circle").transition()
                              .duration(duration)
                              .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + (w - 60) + "," + (-h / 4) + ")"; })
                              .remove();

                          g.select("text").transition()
                              .duration(duration)
                              .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + (w - 60) + "," + (h / 4 - 20) + ")"; })
                              .attr("dy", "0em");

                          g.each(function(d) {
                            y.domain([0, d.maxPrice]);

                            d3.select(this).selectAll(".area")
                                .data(d3.range(3))
                              .enter().insert("path", ".line")
                                .attr("class", "area")
                                .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(0," + (d * (h / 4 - 20)) + ")"; })
                                .attr("d", area(d.values))
                                .style("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); })
                                .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

                            y.domain([0, d.maxPrice / 3]);

                            d3.select(this).selectAll(".line").transition()
                                .duration(duration)
                                .attr("d", line(d.values))
                                .style("stroke-opacity", 1e-6);

                            d3.select(this).selectAll(".area").transition()
                                .duration(duration)
                                .style("fill-opacity", 1)
                                .attr("d", area(d.values))
                                .each("end", function() { d3.select(this).style("fill-opacity", null); });
                          });

                          setTimeout(areas, duration + delay);
                        }

                        function areas() {
                          var g = svg.selectAll(".symbol");

                          axis
                              .y(h / 4 - 21);

                          g.select(".line")
                              .attr("d", function(d) { return axis(d.values); });

                          g.each(function(d) {
                            y.domain([0, d.maxPrice]);

                            d3.select(this).select(".line").transition()
                                .duration(duration)
                                .style("stroke-opacity", 1)
                                .each("end", function() { d3.select(this).style("stroke-opacity", null); });

                            d3.select(this).selectAll(".area")
                                .filter(function(d, i) { return i; })
                              .transition()
                                .duration(duration)
                                .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6)
                                .attr("d", area(d.values))
                                .remove();

                            d3.select(this).selectAll(".area")
                                .filter(function(d, i) { return !i; })
                              .transition()
                                .duration(duration)
                                .style("fill", color(d.key))
                                .attr("d", area(d.values));
                          });

                          svg.select("defs").transition()
                              .duration(duration)
                              .remove();

                          g.transition()
                              .duration(duration)
                              .each("end", function() { d3.select(this).attr("clip-path", null); });

                          setTimeout(stackedArea, duration + delay);
                        }

                        function stackedArea() {
                          var stack = d3.layout.stack()
                              .values(function(d) { return d.values; })
                              .x(function(d) { return d.date; })
                              .y(function(d) { return d.price; })
                              .out(function(d, y0, y) { d.price0 = y0; })
                              .order("reverse");

                          stack(symbols);

                          y
                              .domain([0, d3.max(symbols[0].values.map(function(d) { return d.price + d.price0; }))])
                              .range([h, 0]);

                          line
                              .y(function(d) { return y(d.price0); });

                          area
                              .y0(function(d) { return y(d.price0); })
                              .y1(function(d) { return y(d.price0 + d.price); });

                          var t = svg.selectAll(".symbol").transition()
                              .duration(duration)
                              .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
                              .each("end", function() { d3.select(this).attr("transform", null); });

                          t.select("path.area")
                              .attr("d", function(d) { return area(d.values); });

                          t.select("path.line")
                              .style("stroke-opacity", function(d, i) { return i < 3 ? 1e-6 : 1; })
                              .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); });

                          t.select("text")
                              .attr("transform", function(d) { d = d.values[d.values.length - 1]; return "translate(" + (w - 60) + "," + y(d.price / 2 + d.price0) + ")"; });

                          setTimeout(streamgraph, duration + delay);
                        }

                        function streamgraph() {
                          var stack = d3.layout.stack()
                              .values(function(d) { return d.values; })
                              .x(function(d) { return d.date; })
                              .y(function(d) { return d.price; })
                              .out(function(d, y0, y) { d.price0 = y0; })
                              .order("reverse")
                              .offset("wiggle");

                          stack(symbols);

                          line
                              .y(function(d) { return y(d.price0); });

                          var t = svg.selectAll(".symbol").transition()
                              .duration(duration);

                          t.select("path.area")
                              .attr("d", function(d) { return area(d.values); });

                          t.select("path.line")
                              .style("stroke-opacity", 1e-6)
                              .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); });

                          t.select("text")
                              .attr("transform", function(d) { d = d.values[d.values.length - 1]; return "translate(" + (w - 60) + "," + y(d.price / 2 + d.price0) + ")"; });

                          setTimeout(overlappingArea, duration + delay);
                        }

                        function overlappingArea() {
                          var g = svg.selectAll(".symbol");

                          line
                              .y(function(d) { return y(d.price0 + d.price); });

                          g.select(".line")
                              .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); });

                          y
                              .domain([0, d3.max(symbols.map(function(d) { return d.maxPrice; }))])
                              .range([h, 0]);

                          area
                              .y0(h)
                              .y1(function(d) { return y(d.price); });

                          line
                              .y(function(d) { return y(d.price); });

                          var t = g.transition()
                              .duration(duration);

                          t.select(".line")
                              .style("stroke-opacity", 1)
                              .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); });

                          t.select(".area")
                              .style("fill-opacity", .5)
                              .attr("d", function(d) { return area(d.values); });

                          t.select("text")
                              .attr("dy", ".31em")
                              .attr("transform", function(d) { d = d.values[d.values.length - 1]; return "translate(" + (w - 60) + "," + y(d.price) + ")"; });

                          svg.append("line")
                              .attr("class", "line")
                              .attr("x1", 0)
                              .attr("x2", w - 60)
                              .attr("y1", h)
                              .attr("y2", h)
                              .style("stroke-opacity", 1e-6)
                            .transition()
                              .duration(duration)
                              .style("stroke-opacity", 1);

                          setTimeout(groupedBar, duration + delay);
                        }

                        function groupedBar() {
                          x = d3.scale.ordinal()
                              .domain(symbols[0].values.map(function(d) { return d.date; }))
                              .rangeBands([0, w - 60], .1);

                          var x1 = d3.scale.ordinal()
                              .domain(symbols.map(function(d) { return d.key; }))
                              .rangeBands([0, x.rangeBand()]);

                          var g = svg.selectAll(".symbol");

                          var t = g.transition()
                              .duration(duration);

                          t.select(".line")
                              .style("stroke-opacity", 1e-6)
                              .remove();

                          t.select(".area")
                              .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6)
                              .remove();

                          g.each(function(p, j) {
                            d3.select(this).selectAll("rect")
                                .data(function(d) { return d.values; })
                              .enter().append("rect")
                                .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.date) + x1(p.key); })
                                .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.price); })
                                .attr("width", x1.rangeBand())
                                .attr("height", function(d) { return h - y(d.price); })
                                .style("fill", color(p.key))
                                .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6)
                              .transition()
                                .duration(duration)
                                .style("fill-opacity", 1);
                          });

                          setTimeout(stackedBar, duration + delay);
                        }

                        function stackedBar() {
                          x.rangeRoundBands([0, w - 60], .1);

                          var stack = d3.layout.stack()
                              .values(function(d) { return d.values; })
                              .x(function(d) { return d.date; })
                              .y(function(d) { return d.price; })
                              .out(function(d, y0, y) { d.price0 = y0; })
                              .order("reverse");

                          var g = svg.selectAll(".symbol");

                          stack(symbols);

                          y
                              .domain([0, d3.max(symbols[0].values.map(function(d) { return d.price + d.price0; }))])
                              .range([h, 0]);

                          var t = g.transition()
                              .duration(duration / 2);

                          t.select("text")
                              .delay(symbols[0].values.length * 10)
                              .attr("transform", function(d) { d = d.values[d.values.length - 1]; return "translate(" + (w - 60) + "," + y(d.price / 2 + d.price0) + ")"; });

                          t.selectAll("rect")
                              .delay(function(d, i) { return i * 10; })
                              .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.price0 + d.price); })
                              .attr("height", function(d) { return h - y(d.price); })
                              .each("end", function() {
                                d3.select(this)
                                    .style("stroke", "#fff")
                                    .style("stroke-opacity", 1e-6)
                                  .transition()
                                    .duration(duration / 2)
                                    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
                                    .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
                                    .style("stroke-opacity", 1);
                              });

                          setTimeout(transposeBar, duration + symbols[0].values.length * 10 + delay);
                        }

                        function transposeBar() {
                          x
                              .domain(symbols.map(function(d) { return d.key; }))
                              .rangeRoundBands([0, w], .2);

                          y
                              .domain([0, d3.max(symbols.map(function(d) { return d3.sum(d.values.map(function(d) { return d.price; })); }))]);

                          var stack = d3.layout.stack()
                              .x(function(d, i) { return i; })
                              .y(function(d) { return d.price; })
                              .out(function(d, y0, y) { d.price0 = y0; });

                          stack(d3.zip.apply(null, symbols.map(function(d) { return d.values; }))); // transpose!

                          var g = svg.selectAll(".symbol");

                          var t = g.transition()
                              .duration(duration / 2);

                          t.selectAll("rect")
                              .delay(function(d, i) { return i * 10; })
                              .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.price0 + d.price) - 1; })
                              .attr("height", function(d) { return h - y(d.price) + 1; })
                              .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.symbol); })
                              .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
                              .style("stroke-opacity", 1e-6);

                          t.select("text")
                              .attr("x", 0)
                              .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + (x(d.key) + x.rangeBand() / 2) + "," + h + ")"; })
                              .attr("dy", "1.31em")
                              .each("end", function() { d3.select(this).attr("x", null).attr("text-anchor", "middle"); });

                          svg.select("line").transition()
                              .duration(duration)
                              .attr("x2", w);

                          setTimeout(donut,  duration / 2 + symbols[0].values.length * 10 + delay);
                        }

                        function donut() {
                          var g = svg.selectAll(".symbol");

                          g.selectAll("rect").remove();

                          var pie = d3.layout.pie()
                              .value(function(d) { return d.sumPrice; });

                          var arc = d3.svg.arc();

                          g.append("path")
                              .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.key); })
                              .data(function() { return pie(symbols); })
                            .transition()
                              .duration(duration)
                              .tween("arc", arcTween);

                          g.select("text").transition()
                              .duration(duration)
                              .attr("dy", ".31em");

                          svg.select("line").transition()
                              .duration(duration)
                              .attr("y1", 2 * h)
                              .attr("y2", 2 * h)
                              .remove();

                          function arcTween(d) {
                            var path = d3.select(this),
                                text = d3.select(this.parentNode.appendChild(this.previousSibling)),
                                x0 = x(d.data.key),
                                y0 = h - y(d.data.sumPrice);

                            return function(t) {
                              var r = h / 2 / Math.min(1, t + 1e-3),
                                  a = Math.cos(t * Math.PI / 2),
                                  xx = (-r + (a) * (x0 + x.rangeBand()) + (1 - a) * (w + h) / 2),
                                  yy = ((a) * h + (1 - a) * h / 2),
                                  f = {
                                    innerRadius: r - x.rangeBand() / (2 - a),
                                    outerRadius: r,
                                    startAngle: a * (Math.PI / 2 - y0 / r) + (1 - a) * d.startAngle,
                                    endAngle: a * (Math.PI / 2) + (1 - a) * d.endAngle
                                  };

                              path.attr("transform", "translate(" + xx + "," + yy + ")");
                              path.attr("d", arc(f));
                              text.attr("transform", "translate(" + arc.centroid(f) + ")translate(" + xx + "," + yy + ")rotate(" + ((f.startAngle + f.endAngle) / 2 + 3 * Math.PI / 2) * 180 / Math.PI + ")");
                            };
                          }

                          setTimeout(donutExplode, duration + delay);
                        }

                        function donutExplode() {
                          var r0a = h / 2 - x.rangeBand() / 2,
                              r1a = h / 2,
                              r0b = 2 * h - x.rangeBand() / 2,
                              r1b = 2 * h,
                              arc = d3.svg.arc();

                          svg.selectAll(".symbol path")
                              .each(transitionExplode);

                          function transitionExplode(d, i) {
                            d.innerRadius = r0a;
                            d.outerRadius = r1a;
                            d3.select(this).transition()
                                .duration(duration / 2)
                                .tween("arc", tweenArc({
                                  innerRadius: r0b,
                                  outerRadius: r1b
                                }));
                          }

                          function tweenArc(b) {
                            return function(a) {
                              var path = d3.select(this),
                                  text = d3.select(this.nextSibling),
                                  i = d3.interpolate(a, b);
                              for (var key in b) a[key] = b[key]; // update data
                              return function(t) {
                                var a = i(t);
                                path.attr("d", arc(a));
                                text.attr("transform", "translate(" + arc.centroid(a) + ")translate(" + w / 2 + "," + h / 2 +")rotate(" + ((a.startAngle + a.endAngle) / 2 + 3 * Math.PI / 2) * 180 / Math.PI + ")");
                              };
                            }
                          }

                          setTimeout(function() {
                            svg.selectAll("*").remove();
                            svg.selectAll("g").data(symbols).enter().append("g").attr("class", "symbol");
                            lines();
                          }, duration);
                        }

                        </script>
                    </body>
                </html>
```

I am learning d3.js, so I don't know how to do it. Please help me.

Comment: Can you please make a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) of this?

Comment: Lots of similar posts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9400615/whats-the-best-way-to-make-a-d3-js-visualisation-layout-responsive http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17626555/responsive-d3-chart http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16265123/resize-svg-when-window-is-resized-in-d3-js http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23526856/d3-resize-bar-chart-according-to-window-width http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20885164/how-to-create-a-responsive-map-using-d3

Comment: there is also a [nice off-site resource](https://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2014/02/17/building-responsible-visualizations-d3-js/) on this topic

Comment: @Incodeveritas & Imperative lol yeah, also that. Please actually do research before asking questions on SO, Rahul :)

Comment: You have provided a lot of code here, please consider revising your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Doing this ends up being a bit code heavy, but for my graphs I tend to have 3 different parts: **setup**, **draw** and **redraw**. In **setup** I set up all the SVG containers and bind the data. In **draw**, I do the initial data draw (this tends to have different animations, fade-ins, etc). Then I bind `window.onresize` to the **redraw** all of the SVG data based on window/container dimensions.

I can provide you with an example of my code if you would like.

Comment: Yes I would like to see an example of your code. Also will this work if window is not re-sized but zoomed in zoomed out.